# Xamarin.Forms ListView, how to set RowHeight?

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.forms

The `ListView`in Xamarin.Forms has a `RowHeight`property, but it seems no matter what height I set it to.

I use Visual Studio 2013, I have the business edition license for Xamarin and I use the Android emulator *MonoForAndroid_API_15* and i believe I have the latest version of everything involved.  As of yet I can't run iOS or WinPhone emulators, so I can't compare.  Is this just an issue of the Android emulator or is setting the `RowHeight` property not correct?

Here is my inherited `ContentPage` (note that I set `RowHeight`):

```cs
public class QuizzesPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ListView _listView;

    public QuizzesPage()
    {
        Title = "Test";
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        _listView = new ListView {RowHeight = 20};
        Content = _listView;
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _listView.ItemsSource = new[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
    }
}
```

In `App`:

```cs
public class App
{
    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        return new NavigationPage(new QuizzesPage());
    }
}
```

And this is the visual result:

[image: Androind emulator RowHeight problem]

Note that my code is a simplified version of [the TODO example used by Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Todo/SharedProject/Todo/Views/TodoListPage.cs), where you see them set the `RowHeight` property in the same way as I do.

No matter what I set as `RowHeight` the rows have the same huge height.  What can I do?

**Edit 1:** I plan to upgrade to Windows 8.1 this week and will then be able to test how it looks on WinPhone.  To add a Mac to the network at work I need some permissions first.  This is why I am stuck with only the Android emulator as of yet.

**Edit 2:** I tried setting `HasUnevenRows` to true, as [suggested here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19562/listview-rowheight-always-gives-same-height?new=1), but that only made it accept longer entries, not change the height (or font) of the row, which is way too large for my taste.

**Edit 3:** I posted a solution/workaround as an answer.  At least I get full control over the height of the cells.  But `RowHeight` does not seem to do much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got [this suggestion](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19562/listview-rowheight-always-gives-same-height?new=1):

> Not sure about RowHeight but try setting ListView.HasUnevenRows to true. Then you can specify the height for your cells. Could be that setting this bool is also required when using RowHeight.

This made me realise that I had to create a class that inherits from `ViewCell` and bind to a property on a class:

```cs
public class QuizCell : ViewCell
{
    public QuizCell()
    {
        var label = new Label {HeightRequest = 20};
        label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Title");
        View = label;
    }
}
```

To use this I changed `QuizzesPage` to this:

```cs
public class QuizzesPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ListView _listView;

    public QuizzesPage()
    {
        Title = "Test";
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        _listView = new ListView
                    {
                        HasUnevenRows = true,
                        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof (QuizCell)),
                        //RowHeight = 10
                    };
        Content = _listView;
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var quizEndpoint = new QuizEndpoint("Test");
        var quizzes =  await quizEndpoint.LoadAllAsync();
        _listView.ItemsSource = quizzes;
    }
}
```

The important parts here are:

1. The `ListView`s `ItemSource` is set to a `List<Quiz>` where the `Quiz` object has a `Title` property (the one I bound the `Label` to).
2. The `ListView` sets it `ItemTemplate` method to `new DataTemplate(typeof (QuizCell))`, which is the new class I created.

Now I can set the height to a row to whatever I want using the `HeightRequest` property of the component used in class inherited from `ViewCell`.

The reason for my problems was that I simplified [the TODO example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Todo/SharedProject/Todo/Views/TodoListPage.cs) too much (and that `RowHeight` does not seem to accomplish much).  Also, in conclusion, this had nothing to do with the emulator.  I hope this helps someone!